# Which Banjo bolts do I need for Zee M640 calipers?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, brakes, disc-brake

I've just ordered a set of Zee M640 calipers to replace the old BR-M596 2 piston calipers on a bike I bought recently.
While looking for other parts I need I  noticed that the calipers don't come with Banjo bolts.

I will have to make new hoses up with Banjo fittings, but I'm not sure which Banjo bolts I need and I can't find anything about it online, can anyone help?
I'm in the UK and I don't have a good bike shop near me (just a Halfords and they are useless) so everything has to be bought online.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[You need Y8H098010](https://si.shimano.com/en/ev/BR-M640-R-3449) if you'll be doing this with Shimano hoses.

[image]

Comment: That's great,thank you mate